# Why is the matrix in Dirac's bracket formula invertible?

Tags: matrices, sg.symplectic-geometry

I am reading the book "Introduction to mechanics and symmetry" by J.Marsden and T.Ratiu and am experenced a problem.

Let $(P,\Omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, a submanifold $S\subset P$ is called a symplectic submanifold when $\omega:=i^*\Omega$ is a symplectic form on $S, i:S\rightarrow P$ being the inclusion.  Assume that $\dim P=2n,\dim S=2k$. In a neighborhood of a point $z_0\in S$, choose coordinates $z^1,...,z^{2n}$ on $P$ such that $S$ is given by $$z^{2k+1}=0,...,z^{2n}=0,$$
and so $z^1,...,z^{2k}$ provide the local coordinates for $S$.

In the formulation of Dirac's bracket formula, it appears the inverse of the matrix defined by $$C^{ij}(z)=\{z^i,z^j\},\ i,j=2k+1,...,2n.$$

The author said that it is easy to see one can choose coordinates such that the matrix $C=\{C^{ij}\}$ is invertible. But I cannot see the reason.

Thank you if you can give a short proof or refer me to a good reference.

Chengbo

Comment: That matrix is invertible in any coordinates.

Comment: Can you show me a proof or some reference?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is discussed, perhaps not completely clearly, in Henneaux and Teitelboim, **Quantization of Gauge Systems**. Princeton University Press, 1992. They prove, in chapter two, that the Dirac bracket is precisely the Poisson bracket of $S$ determined by the symplectic form $\Omega|_S$ which is the pullback of $\Omega$ from $P$. In fact, this approach is preferable over the use of Dirac brackets, as I understand the story, because pulling back differential forms is a more elementary operation than generating these elaborate Dirac brackets.

Comment: I was about to give an answer based on this reference too; the relevant bit is Theorem 2.5. Most relevant to OP's question are the expressions in Eqs. 2.22a and 2.22b which show that invertibility of $C$ follows from the fact that $\Omega$, being symplectic on $P$, is nondegenerate and also nondegenerate on $S$.

Comment: Ben Mckay and J.c., thank you! I think that I will be able to work out the problem.